# Android webview not showing properly

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have an Android WebView and it is just showing the proper blue background of the site, but none of the content. I have the same site opening properly in an iOS webview.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
                    if (url.contains("test.com")) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                // Otherwise allow the OS to handle things like tel, mailto, etc.
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity( intent );
                return true;
            }
        });

        mWebView.loadUrl("https://test.com");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding:

```
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

fixed the issue.

Comment: Accept it as an answer if this fixed your issue.

Comment: I have to wait 2 days before I can do that